# lvm and data recovery

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I am having a Windows 7 laptop (500GB hard drive ) initially with 3 partitions ( *C : around 100 GB* and rest equally between *D* and *E* ) and one system reserved (very small around 400MB )(total 4).

Unaware of the fact that if we create 5 partitions in windows lead to change in basic disk to dynamic disk I did that and Created *F* by dividing *D* equally but I undo the operation by moving very small amount of data of *D* to *E* and merging all the drive to E.

Until this point I was having a * C(same) , E(around 300 GB) and F (around 100 GB (totally empty))* but not as basic one but as a dynamic disk.

Now I tried to install ubuntu onto the *F* drive but Ubuntu didn't find my partitions there. It showed me only 2 partitions: one was system reserved for Windows and the other of ~480 GB all of partitions as one (all because of dynamic disk). In this confused state I choose the option of *lvm* and clicked ok ([as shown in figure](http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/img_55035707bbd74.png)). It showed me the option to write the changes or not. I clicked on *Go Back* and powered off the pc, But when I turned it back on I saw that Windows would not boot up and by checking the hard disk status from Ubuntu booted pen drive and seeing it as [image: gparted image]

My laptop hard drive is currently having one volume group *ubuntu-vg* consisting of 2 logical volume *root* and *swap_1*. I am unable to mount the root partition due to filesystem error. I have tried using logical volume manager which shows fs as none. Is there any way to recover the data from root *lv*?

```
  sudo fsck /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
  fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
  e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
  ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
  fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
  fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root

  The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
  filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
  filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
  is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
     e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
      or
     e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

- It might have occurred that while Ubuntu created lvm2 it wipes the whole memory , please ans me if it has occurred.
- as far as i understood volume group and logical volume is just an abstraction . there can be a chance that data still resides in physical disk but i am not able to see it .
- while trying to mount the logical volume it shows me fs error .
- running `ls` cmd shows me output

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Oct 26 18:54 /dev/ubuntu-vg/root -> ../dm-0`

- what will if i run `lvremove` cmd to delete the logical view and then I be able to access physical volumes or they it will format the data.

output of `ls -lL /dev/ubuntu-vg/root`

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252, 0 Oct 26 19:35 /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
```

Comment: yes , not working

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the output of `fsck`?

Comment: please have a look

Comment: So I assume you have already tried what the output suggests: `e2fsck -f -b 32768 /dev/sdb1`!? Do you still remember what file system was it?

Comment: yes i have alredy tried the 'e2fsck' it shows the same output as 'fsck' . Initially this pc was not a linux one, it was on windows and will trying to boot ubuntu , i choose the wrong option of lvm and even then did the option to go back but it made the *vg* and logical volumes , so this lead to not booting up windows because lvm forms an abstraction over the C drive .

Comment: what will happen if i use 'lvremove' to delete the logical view will then it will show me the physical view

Comment: please @roaima have a look , made all what i did clear.

Comment: Sorry @roaima , added the output !

Comment: In your first paragraph you describe a 500GB disk split as C: as 100GB, D: as 200GB and E: as 200GB (with a small amount for Windows' System Reserved partition). These take up your entire disk. So where did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: as explained in next one i created a 5th one by spliting d drive equally , which lead to making the whole disk dynamic

Comment: but finally before start of boot operation i merged the remaining d i.e.(100gb) to E (200) thus total of 300 in E with my data , 100 gb in C with os and some files on desktop and 100 gb F (5th one created out of D ) empty for ubuntu

Comment: Ah. When you write "_Now I tried to boot the F with Ubuntu but didn't find my partitions there_" do you really mean "_Now I tried to INSTALL Ubuntu onto the F: drive, but Ubuntu but didn't find my partitions there_"? That's really quite an important difference

Comment: you got it while i was just typing the comment , i will edit it too

Comment: And now you've accidentally converted the Dynamic Disk to LVM. Ah!

Comment: exectly !! and even don't know is the data and physical partitions still there or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the LVM signature with `pvremove /dev/sda5`. I would strongly recommend you read the man page before running this command.

The [EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard](http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/dynamic-disks-recovery.htm) claims to recover data from lost partitions on a damaged Dynamic Disk. You will need a spare disk to which the data can be written.

IMO, you may have lost your entire disk, so I would prepare to recover what data you can, and expect to have to reinstall from scratch. Unfortunately.

Comment: The question not at all off-topic. there was no problem in drive even when i made it dynamic . it actually started when ubuntu created lvm on to it. until and unless ubuntu don't remove this layer of abstraction any of the windwos software can't do anything at least like EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard.

Comment: @user197076 I have added some additional information for you that may be useful